# PHP - вывести массив

Tags: php

Есть массив

```
Array ( [0] => aaaaaa 
        [1] => IN/123
        [2] => bbbbbb
        [3] => /IN/124
       )
```

Как вывести его чтобы получилось:

aaaaaa - IN/123

bbbbbb - /IN/124

В цикле for и увеличением счетчика на +1 для второго элемента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$chunks = array_chunk($your_array, 2);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo implode('-', $chunk);
}
```

Comment: вот почему в js не таких удобных функций, а в пхп их куча?)

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i +=2)
  echo $data[$i] . ' - ' . $data[$i + 1];
```